# Owl Carousel 2 - Bug on loop

Tags: jquery, instagram, instagram-api, owl-carousel, instafeedjs

The problem is when I **drag** to the **instafeed slider**, the **instafeed** disappears.
Example:

[image: before drag. on the left -> instafeed]

When I drag, it disappears like this:

[image]

And the slider hide the instagram photos.
[image]

Link for test:
http://mindvelopers.com/test/test.php

This is my code:

Instafeed:

```
var feedslider = new Instafeed({

get: 'user',
userId: 240284198,
accessToken: '<?php echo $settings['instagram_token']; ?>',
limit: 18,
sortBy: 'most-recent',
target: 'instagram_slider',
after: function () {
    var images = $("#instagram_slider").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
        var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
        $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
        $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
        $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
        $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
        $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
        $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
},

});

feedslider.run();
```

OWL CAROUSEL:

```
$(function(){

$('#home-slider').owlCarousel({
center: true,
animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
animateIn: 'flipInX',
items:3,
autoWidth:true,
loop:true,
margin:0,
responsive:{600:{items:3}}     
});

});
```

PS: I have no errors on console.

EDIT: 
The problem is that owl carousel clone the sliders.
But instafeed cant duplicate ID's.
Now I need to duplicate instafeed. how to?

Comment: I do not see the Instafeed on the left at all on this page when I visit your link. I see an Instagram slider when I drag to the right. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When you drag to the right, can you see instagram images? Look at the update.

Comment: My last check shows an empty div for the id=instagram_slider

Comment: Now i know the problem. The slider doesn't clone #ID's

Comment: So the problem now is, how to append the instafeed data to an class instead ID

Comment: If you want to continue using the same plugin just change this ID https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/instafeed.js#L185 to `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I've changed that. But it still isn't cloning :(

Comment: Dang. I'm not quite sure but obviously the two plugins are conflicting. I see another ID. Not sure if its relevant? I'm not familiar with the plugin but thought I'd offer what I saw.     `header.removeChild(document.getElementById('instafeed-fetcher'));`